# Many copies of svchost.exe running

Tags: windows-xp, svchost

In Windows XP, I see that there are many copies of a process called `scvhost.exe`, some running as local services, some other as network services and yet some other owned by the system. One of this copies is using up to 50% of the processor (I'm using Windows XP as a Guest OS in VirtualBox with two cores, Host OS is Debian 7), and every time it runs starts throwing high temp alerts. To stop the warnings, I frequently kill the process, and the problem goes away.

So, my questions are:

- What is this `svchost.exe` process?
- Why are there so many copies running?
- Is it a good idea to kill the process? (Windows seems to work just normally with or without that "cpu-hungry" `svchost.exe` process running)
- Can I, somehow, tweak the configuration to stop this "rogue" copy of the process?

I will appreciate any help.

Comment: maybe you have the WindowsUpdate bug: http://www.neowin.net/news/microsoft-still-trying-to-fix-svchost-bug-in-windows-xp

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**The `svchost.exe` process is the Windows Service Host. It is the application in charge of running services** (which can be accessed by going to a prompt/run box and typing `services.msc`). Each executable is tasked with running one or several services (depends on the specific service). **There are many copies because there are many services on your computer, and many processes are required to maintain all of them.** However, because they're all named the same, it's hard to differentiate the `svchost.exe` processes from each other. **Therefore, it's not *exactly* safe to just end an `svchost.exe` process from Task Manager; instead, it's safer to go into the Services management console at `services.msc` and end services from there**, because if you end the wrong process from the Task Manager, you could accidentally kill a number of things, including,

- Dropbox, Google Drive, or some other file sync software
- Audio playback and recording capabilities
- Internet connectivity
- Daemons, servers, etc.

**If you want to stop high CPU load as a result of the Services host, you should consider stopping, or disabling some resources from the Services management console, or uninstall some unnecessary software that might have installed a CPU-intensive service.** 

*Please do note that malware has been known to infect `svchost.exe` in the past due to its commodity and expected high performance, giving it an ideal place to hide. Therefore, you should also consider running a malware check of some sort.*